# Are there any phase III clinical trials of probiotics?

Tags: research, probiotics

Probiotics are used by a large number of people. I know there is research on their efficacy, but have any studied reached what would reasonably be considered a phase III clinical trial?

Comment: Testing for efficacy in what?

Comment: Any of their purported benefits. Anything. Are there any phase III clinical trials showing probiotics are useful at treating something?

Comment: If Graham's comment was useful to you, please edit your question to include this clarifying/added detail to your question. Comments are volatile and may disappear at any time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can search on the clinical trials website to find most of the trials conducted with probiotics.

Eg. `https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/results?intr=%22Lactobacillus%22` gives currently 589 results, some of which are described as phase 3 studies.  You can change the search term to `acidophilus` or whatever you're interested in.